# What is an indicator that a question is "too broad" or not?

Tags: discussion, needs-more-focus

What is the line between broad and too broad?

As I understand "question put on Hold because: TOO broad" mean that a question is not only broad, but TOO broad for an good answer (and therefore the question should be put on hold to be refined or closed).

But when a question already have good answers then I have the feeing that it can not be TOO broad, because this was the definition/reason for "TOO broad".

Is my understanding correct: **a broad ANSWERABLE question is ok, but a "TOO broad" question without chance for good answers should be closed?**

Comment: "So what are other useful use cases for AspectJ and AOP?" -- this is a broad question. I cannot answer that with a definitive, factual, and complete answer. I could give you some opinions, some examples that I know of, but to exhaustively list every "useful use case" is a vast (read: broad) subject. Define "useful"! Define "some"!

Comment: I can think of 3 completely different answers to your meta question that are all equally valid.  Your question is too broad :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the first person commenting advises you to read a book, it is probably too broad.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. If someone is asking how to animate a menubar using CSS, but it is clear from their question that they don't understand how CSS works, you'd advice them to read a book/tutorial to lean the basics of CSS first, and then tackle their specific problem.

Comment: @bigblind: I didn't advise to read a book. It was about the question being broad or not. You need a minimal understanding of the problem to get an anwer.

Answer (score 14):

The dividing line between broad and too broad is a little bit sketchy, but I think the specific case you linked to is pretty clear. I agree that it's too broad. It would probably be closed immediately by the community if asked today.

Your question is: **What is AspectJ good for?**

The "too broad" close reason says:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format.

You asked an open-ended question about the usefulness of AspectJ in particular and Aspect Oriented Programming in general. The answers to that question would either be a list or a book on AspectJ/AOP. The top answer to your question is a list, and the second answer directs you to a Wikipedia article. Those are both good indicators that you've asked a question that's too broad.

Comment: I agree for the example, but what is the answer for this meta question?

Comment: @Ralph: Comprehensively, correctly and precisely defining the line between *broad* and *too broad* is *far too broad* a question: SkyNet looks downright easy in comparison.