# How to help people who need a lot of knowledge to answer their question?

Tags: discussion

Before I come to my actual point, I'd like to say that I'm going to use the asker of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27792890/can-i-clean-browser-realted-history-cache-using-java-script/27793174?noredirect=1) as an example, and I'll say some negative things about his technical knowledge. I don't do this to attack him personally, he's probably a great guy, but I wanted to have a real example here.

His question makes it fairly clear to me that he doesn't at all understand caching, which is the main focus of the question, and there seem to be a lot of layers of knowledge about the web, and browsers (he's closing them using ctrl+alt+del), that he's missing.

And this happens quite often, where people need a lot of background info to understand the answer to their question.

I'm glad to help people out, but I don't want to write a book about the web in a SO answer. What would be the right approach here?

Looking further into this, it looks like he has the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), the resources aren't updated when he wants them to be, so he tries to manually clear the cache from JavaScript. While the actual problem is that the page is cached, not that it can't be cleared from js.

Comment: I would go with closing as 'too broad'.

Comment: The question isn't too broad. He's just asking if JavaScript can clear the cache when the user performs certain actions.

Comment: Yes, that's an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Close quickly, you can post a link to the meta question in a comment if you wish.

Comment: see also: [What is an indicator that a question is “too broad” or not?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268314/839601) "If the first person commenting advises you to read a book, it is probably too broad."

Comment: I'm not really sure I'd agree with that. Sometimes you need a broad base of knowledge to understand a specific answer.