# Questions are more likely to get killed than improved

Tags: discussion, downvotes

It is becoming increasingly difficult to ask legitimate programming questions on Stack Overflow. I've seen:

1. Users downvote questions into oblivion before OP can act on their comments. By the time a question reaches a ranking of -5 it is impossible to get enough traffic to dig your way back up.
2. Users downvote questions without providing any explanation. **This happens a lot**. Sometimes people simply misunderstand the question. Other times they don't like what is being asked ("Why would you need this? Do X instead"). Maybe OP has legitimate reasons for going in a certain direction but before they can explain they are downvoted into oblivion.

What I'm asking is, **what can we do to place more value on recovering problematic questions than closing/deleting them?**

Stack Overflow places pressure on the person posting a question to do so (deleting too many questions prevents one from posting new questions altogether) but it is an unrealistic expectation because of the above problems (no way to recover once you've been downvoted too many times) and because there is insufficient pressure on the voters to take the time to understand the question before voting. Further, if questions are improved the users who downvoted it do not get notified to revisit their vote.

**The crux of the problem I am trying to highlight is that it is extremely difficult for questions with a negative rank to regain votes even if they are edited to perfection. Search engines simply stop directing traffic to them.**

Comment: Except your questions are now at a net "0" so you are receiving upvotes.

Comment: @Paulie_D This was not the case when I first posted this question. Had I not linked from meta to them I would still be sitting on a negative rank :)

Comment: ..and if you have legitimate explanations for going in a certain direction **include them in the question from the start-**

Comment: That's what you *think* but you don't *know* that. I don't see you complaining about upvotes with no explanations.

Comment: @Paulie_D I do most of the time. Sometimes people bring up objections that I didn't think to address up-front. By the time I do, they downvoted me to oblivion. I can't sit by the keyboard 24/7 posting a reply immediately after they comment. Sometimes comments arrive in the middle of the night.

Comment: 2 negative votes is not *oblivion*...a little less hyperbole would go a long way.

Comment: @Paulie_D By "oblivion" I mean "low enough that search engines stop directing traffic to the question". I don't know what the cutoff line is, but certainly I've never seen questions with a rank of less than -5 ever recover. In many cases -2 never recovers either. Also please note that I am referring to -2 overall ranking, not 2 negative votes.

Comment: Far too often people don't bother editing their question into a better shape, I'm not gonna wait around on the off-chance that the OP does edit, I vote as the question is when I view it. Which is why you should  take extra care to post your question in the best shape when you submit it

Comment: @Epodax As you should, but when OP *does* edit in good faith we should provide sufficient traffic so you and others can up-vote the question again.

Comment: It's news to me that search engines stop directing traffic to negatively voted questions, but if they are, that's great and should not be changed under any circumstances! Closed questions polluting the Google index has been pissing me off for a long time. Encouraging improving questions (and giving them a real chance to recuperate) is a separate issue and would be a good thing but so far we haven't managed to come up with any ideas that look really good and workable.

Comment: I always thought closing and deleting problematic questions was our core business. Not doing that is left to the competition (quora, reddit, Yahoo! Answers)

Comment: To me, your questions seem great. You must've just hit an angry crowd. :)

Comment: The "ThreadPoolExecutor" seems more like a work order than a question, IMO.

Comment: @yivi It's a tough question. If I had any code to provide up-front I would have. I will likely post sub-questions that build up individual components of the solution then link to them from the original question. I always post the top-level question first in case someone knows of an existing solution (e.g. library or existing stackoverflow post).

Comment: Looking for "existing solutions" makes it look even more like a work order and even less fitting for SO.

Comment: @yivi The vast majority of SO posts are composed of "existing solutions" in one form or another. Good answers provide references by way of quotes and existing code.

Comment: TBH, I was not over-impressed by the 'timing' one either.  It may be possible to specify nanosecond precision but, in a software context, nanosecond accuracy is unattainable except with dedicated, embedded controllers.  I dodn't downvote it, but I didn't feel any pressing desire to upvote it either:(

Comment: ... The OP is trying to improve their question, so (meta) upvote.

Comment: @MartinJames You missed the point of the question. If a user specifies a rate of 1 token per 1000 ns and 100 ms has elapsed, then I need to refill 100,000 tokens. It doesn't matter whether the machine is capable of measuring nanosecond precision. What matters is that the user is able to specify rates in terms of nanoseconds, and the implementation should grant the appropriate number of tokens. The greater the precision the machine runs on, the finer-grained the rate at which the tokens will be granted.

Comment: @user202729 But they *aren't* asking how to improve  their questions.  They're asserting that their questions are good, even though people are downvoting them, and saying that people shouldn't be downvoting their questions because they aren't problematic.  They're also claiming (falsely) that questions aren't given any opportunity for improvement.

Comment: @Servy ... I agree that the claim is false. But I don't think the OP is "asserting that their question are good".

Comment: @user202729 To quote the question, "Although I don't think there is anything wrong with the above questions."

Comment: @Servy Which has just been deleted in the most recent revision.

Comment: @user202729 Because they wanted to remove all reference to the questions, which makes it all the more clear that they're not looking for help improving those questions.  They apparently didn't like getting feedback on how the questions were problematic, so they removed them *because* they got feedback on them, when they didn't want it.

Comment: @Servy No. I am simply getting tired of the abuse dished out on this thread. I tried to bring up a legitimate concern. You might disagree with my opinion but it is just that: my opinion. I don't care enough to argue with people who are trying to nitpick me to death. You want to be right? Okay, fine. You're right.

Comment: @Gili I find it rather telling that you consider people explaining to you why your questions are problematic and how you can fix them "abuse".  That you aren't interested in listening to that feedback or fixing your posts is exactly why your posts doing recover when they get downvoted/closed.  It's because you don't fix them, not because questions that get fixed and can't recover.

Comment: @Servy You're absolutely right. I am clearly wrong. There is nothing more to say.

Comment: You raised an issue and linked to questions supporting your case. People disagreed with the issue described, and disagreed that the linked questions supported your case. That's a far cry from "dishing abuse". Do not take it personally, please, it doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 15):

> What can we do to place more value on recovering problematic questions than closing/deleting them?

Honestly, people need to take more time to describe their problem and make sure that it's appropriate for the site from the start. I don't think it's fair to dump responsibility on voters to update their votes later, or on the community to re-review old questions. The question should have been good from the beginning.

The problem is this: so few people actually try to improve their question, I'm starting to give up on lower quality posts. For the longest time, I've been trying to spoon feed advice to newer users to help them improve their posts with the hope that *eventually*, they'll learn and begin to improve. I try going back over, in the hopes that in the meantime they've corrected their question. What I seeinstead:

- There's either no response from the OP, or they begin diving into "just give me the code so I can leave" territory.
- They make a very minor edit that addresses maybe one of the problems, but still leaves their question with glaring problems like still being overly broad or vague.
- Maybe one in every 20 times, someone will actually improve their post to the point where a previous downvote can justifiably be removed, or even reversed to an upvote.

At this point, it's hard to justify to myself to go back over old posts, or continue to give the same effort that I previously had when I know that my efforts will almost surely be wasted.

What's the solution? Just make sure the post is good from the start!

That's sounds like a bad solution since "good" is subjective, but really, it's the best solution. When we have *so* many new questions every minute, there's only so much time we can devote to older questions. If the person had just posted a good question from the start, they could have had their answer in minutes, and everyone could have moved on.

That may sound unfair since there's no way to know for sure how a question sounds to someone else, or if you've supplied enough information for someone to he able to help you. At this point though, I can ask a good question with almost a 100% success rate, so it's not unobtainable, as long as you keep some things in mind:

- You *must* have tried solving this yourself first. Show your work! Lay out your debugging efforts so we don't have to play a game of 20 Questions in the comments to flesh out what's already been tried. That wastes the community's time and takes people away from askers who are willing to put effort in.
- You must have a clear question. If you can't formulate a clear question, you haven't dug for long enough. When someone dumps a "I don't know what's wrong, help!" question without indicating any effort that they've gone through, it's becoming harder and harder for me to believe that if they didn't put in any effort before, suddenly they will as soon as they get some help.
- You should "baby sit" your question for the first ~5 minutes after posting; the critical window. If it's important enough to you that you're asking for help, it's important enough for you to be responsive in the comments when unforeseen issues pop up. If you get a rush of enthusiastic helpers trying to help you, but you ignore them (even if it's just because you aren't paying attention), that's on you. The help was there, you just passed it up. Of course, this doesn't apply when you don't get any comments at all, but usually in those cases the question has deep flaws that can't easily be corrected, and a new visit to the site tour would be beneficial.

In short, *prove to the community, from the start, that your question is worth their time investment*. There are far too many questions to try and help everybody. If I peek at a question and it's clear that they have put in next to no effort, I may just pass, since there's likely another question somewhere else at the same time that I could be working on.

I'll admit, this doesn't *actually* address the main question, but I think this may be an XY Problem. We shouldn't even need to go over old posts, so there doesn't need be a process to do so. The problem is that problematic posts are occurring at all.

---

Note, I'm using "you" here generally; not specifically referring to Gili. It's simpler than writing "then asker of bad questions" everywhere.

Answer (score 14):

To me, most of those "downvote to oblivion" could be prevented if a poster would take time to re-read his question in a different mindset than his own before posting. I usually ask if a question is vague but there are also questions with only code but no actual question. Or with described problem but no code. Or just posting something sheningans taking our time to decipher what the problem actually is.

Everyone that is contributing on Stackoverflow.com is doing that with their spare time (well... theoretically seen. I did answer some questions during my work hours). I tend to ask for some clarification or details first if there is a question that is not so clear. If there is a "code-for-me-pl0x" question, I vote a close flag it and/or continue with checking other questions.

I have taken time to check your two linked questions:

> [How to divide one Duration by another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49216922/how-to-divide-one-duration-by-another)

This one has 3 up- and 3 downvotes. I admit that I do not comprehend the downvote after checking your edit history. Seems a fine question although the setup could be explained a bit better.

> [Non-blocking rate-limited ThreadPoolExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206773/non-blocking-rate-limited-threadpoolexecutor)

This is just a too broad question. It can be solved in many ways. A better approach is to do some research yourself, implement it or go to [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Then I took time to check your question history. You have posted 458 questions, so could not check 'm all. But most of those are pretty decent or good. So you do know how to write a decent question.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review my questions and provide constructive feedback.

Comment: I have a question regarding your answer. Having read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268307/14731 I am not clear on the definition of "too broad" in the context of Stackoverflow. Don't **all** programming questions have many possible answers? It's not like I'm asking about the general merits of AspectJ. I am asking for a specific programming solution (any will do) that meets a specific set of requirements.

Comment: Can you make explicit how this answers *what can we do to place more value on recovering problematic questions than closing/deleting them?* and *The crux of the problem I am trying to highlight is that it is extremely difficult for questions with a negative rank to regain votes even if they are edited to perfection. Search engines simply stop directing traffic to them.*. Doesn't your answer and the current voting on those two questions simply prove the whole premises of the question to be invalid?

Comment: @rene "_Doesn't your answer and the current voting on those two questions simply prove the whole premises of the question to be invalid?_" --> yes. It is ironic right ?

Comment: @rene These questions did not reach a rank of -5 or lower, so I fail to see how this invalidates the premise of the question.

Comment: @Gili So the questions you used as an example are not meant to illustrate the perceived issue, it is just a way for you to attract more eyes on your own questions. Mission %&&%$# accomplished. Can you share some other examples then that are -5 or lower and have value and are closed or deleted by me or others?

Comment: @rene I can't figure out how to search SO for questions with a rank less than -5. Can you? In the meantime, riddle me this. Why does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49216922/how-to-divide-one-duration-by-another have 6 negative votes?

Comment: @Gili because 6 people thought it wasn't a useful question, or that it wasn't well researched, or that it was unclear. One of them might have lost their keys.

Comment: @Gili yes I can: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A..-5+is%3Aq+closed%3Ayes

Answer (score 11):

> Although I don't think there is anything wrong with the above questions

The fact that you don't see anything wrong with them is precisely why it's important for other users to provide the feedback to you that they're problematic, by downvoting/closing them.  If they just ignored the problems with those posts you wouldn't have been informed that your posts were problematic.  Because of them,  you were.

> Users downvote my question into oblivion before I can act on their comments.

Indeed, it's important for everyone to have feedback on the quality of those posts.  Now other readers won't have to spend a bunch of time reading your posts to realize they're problematic, as they've gotten a signal from other users.

> By the time a question reaches a ranking of -5 it is impossible to get enough traffic to dig your way back up.

It happens a *lot*.  When people really *do* improve their posts and fix the problems that they had they tend to do pretty well.  You haven't really demonstrated that posts that really do fix their problems consistently don't recover.

> Users downvote my question without providing any explanation.

But you were just saying above that you *did* get comments saying how your posts could be improved, so apparently that isn't true.  Not that they're obligated to anyway.  There are *lots* of resources out there on how to ask good questions; they don't need to be repeated on every bad question.

Additionally, you've have now asked **over 450 questions**.  I think readers of your questions can reasonably expect you to *already* be familiar with how to ask good questions.  That you haven't figured it out by now also means you're pretty clearly not interested in asking good questions.  Anyone who spent time trying to help you fix your posts would be wasting their time.  If you were going to learn how to ask questions well, you'd have done it by now.

> Sometimes people simply misunderstand the question.

If your question is so unclear that the readers aren't understanding it them your post *merits* downvotes.  It is *your* responsibility to ensure that the question is clear and will be understood.

> Other times they don't like what I'm asking

Again, if they don't think that the question or its answer would be useful we *want* them to downvote it.  It is also your responsibility to ensure that the question is a useful question.

> what can we do to place more value on recovering problematic questions than closing/deleting them?

We *want* bad questions to be closed as soon as possible.  It prevents low quality answers from being posted until the question author has an opportunity to improve them.

Questions *aren't* deleted quickly.  The author is typically given several days at a minimum, usually even longer, to improve their question.  It is only after they've clearly indicated that they're not interested in improving their posts that they get deleted.

> Search engines simply stop directing traffic to them.

This one just isn't true.  Search engines *do* direct people to lower scored questions.  They aren't shown on the homepage, but they're still indexed and visible from the questions lists.

Answer (score 6):

> The crux of the problem I am trying to highlight is that it is extremely difficult for questions with a negative rank to regain votes even if they are edited to perfection.

This is a *good thing*. Yes, really.

It is important to recognize that asking a bad question takes up other people's time. Getting into a comment thread asking where we tell people what's wrong with their question takes up people's time.

That a bad question might get turned into a not-bad question is a perfectly legitimate possibility. However, the time and effort it takes to do that takes time away from experts who want to answer *good* questions. Those experts who are tied up with bad questions aren't spending time asking questions that *start* as good questions.

That's not good.

We don't want people to ask bad questions and then edit them into good ones; we want them to ask good ones *in the first place*. The fact that bad questions that are not quickly edited into good ones cannot reasonably recover is therefore appropriate *punishment* for asking such a bad question in the first place.

Nobody has a gun to your head, forcing you to ask a bad question. That was your choice. We shouldn't have to take our time to explain why it was a bad question, nor does your re-edited version merit equal consideration to the question from someone who took the time and effort to get it right the first time.